# Which technology is used?

Tags: django

I am thinking which technology is needed for making copy of this web service: http://dziswieczorem.pl/
Does someone know any almoust-ready solution (especially for map-things) implemented in django?
Or maybe could anyone give me tips in which technology it would be easier to implement something like that?

To be more concrete:
Is there some ready template containing world map like on page that I wrote about above? I also need a chat feature.

Comment: You're going to have to be way more specific with what you're trying to learn from your question, or this is going to get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the map functionality, you may get some benefit from `django-gmapi`, but I've never tried it so I don't know if it's exactly what you want or not.

As far as chat, there seem to be a few options here that you could consider: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/chat/

Comment: I will consider things you wrote about. Thank you.